# Very strange bug in Unity (or less likely in Gimp and Skype) - some windows dont show anything

Tags: 14.04, unity, skype, gui, gimp

Sometimes when I start Gimp main window looks like this:

[image]

After a few restarts of Gimp everything renders OK.

Sometimes I can also reporduce this bug with Skype:

[image]

In this case it helps just to move a window or open/close it.

There is no such issue with any other application.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64, Gimp 2.8.10, Skype 4.3.0.37-1. It's a laptop Fujitsu Lifebook E733 (Core i7 3632QM 2200 Mhz, Intel HD Graphics 4000).

I compared outputs of Gimp started with --verbose flag in case when bug reproduces and when it doesn't. Didn't found any difference. Skype doesn't support --verbose flag.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu tracks this as the following bug in Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1371928

In case of Nvidia GPUs, this is traced to the following bug in compiz: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206

And users are reporting that it still happens to them in 2015, so it is apparently not fixed. A workaround could be to not use Unity and/or compiz.

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206/comments/21 for a possible "solution"

Comment: OK, for now I disabled animation in ccsm. Will see if it fixes a problem.